# FontAwesome loading but not displaying in Chrome, Safari or Firefox (displays small boxes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fonts, ruby-on-rails-3.2, font-face

On Rails 3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.2, I have font-awesome.css, font-awesome.min.css and font-awesome-ie7.min.css in an app/assets/fonts directory.

Here is the @import declaration I am using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
    src: url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
    url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I am telling the application to load and compile the fonts folder as part of the asset pipeline in config/application.rb like so:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I also have the following in my application.css file:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require ./../fonts/font-awesome
```

Finally, this is my HTML:

```
<i class="icon-facebook"></i>
```

The problem is that where the icons should be displaying, there is instead a small little box that displays. I have this in my app's main css file:

```
i {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

... but that doesn't display the icons either.

font-awesome.css seems to be loading correctly, as this appears in the source code:

```
<link href="/assets/font-awesome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Why are these small little boxes showing up in place of the icons? Clearly I am missing something ...

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Still don't know why the above isn't working, but I ended up creating a link relation to an externally hosted font-awesome stylesheet in my  tag, as follows:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I would still rather find a solution to the above though in case something goes wrong with the linked site.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having a similar issue where css files are loading fine but the icons are not showing up until I start the inspector on Chrome. It only happens on Chrome. So frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

I use the same rails version with Ruby 1.9.3 + bootstrap and font-awesome and have it working perfectly fine. If it can help here what I did

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.2.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails', '3.0.0.1'
```

In **assets/stylesheets application.css.scss** add this line

```
 *= require _font-awesome
```

In **assets/javascripts/application.js** add this line

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Then I have a stylesheet where I import bootstrap and override what I want called '**bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss**
At the top of this file (very first line) I put

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

And that's all... Font-awesome displays fine (text as well as icons)...

Hope this can help you

Cheers